# Equivalent diagram of a transformer

Tags: transformer

In equivalent diagram of a transformer why don't we take the value of winding reactance? For example, let

[image]

here in this RL circuit we have taken the value of reactance, but the equivalent diagram of transformer we take only leakage reactance not the winding reactance.

[image: Equivalent transformer we take only leakage reactance]

Answer (score 2):

> *but the equivalent diagram of transformer we take only leakage
> reactance not the winding reactance*

[image]

It normally totally overshadows the leakage reactance in value so it's a good approximation for many transformer examples.